# php compare string of keywords

Tags: php, compare, keyword, substr

I need to compare these two strings of keywords with php.

```
$original_keywords = cat, dog, mouse

$possible_keywords_1 = "cat, dog, hamster";       
$possible_keywords_2 = "cat, sheep, goat";
```

I need the a php script to assign numerical values of "1" to the first possible string (1 match) and "2" to the second (2 matches). Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

```
$original_keywords = array("cat", "dog", "mouse");
$possible_keywords1 = preg_split('/,\s*/', "cat, dog, hamster");
echo count(array_intersect($original_keywords, $possible_keywords1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$original_keywords = "cat, dog, mouse";
$possible_keywords_1 = "cat, dog, hamster";
$possible_keywords_2 = "cat, sheep, goat";

// Put the input keywords into an array
$keywords = explode(', ', $original_keywords);

// Put all incoming keywords into one big array (you can add as many arrays
// as you want here)
$input = array_merge(
    explode(', ', $possible_keywords_1),
    explode(', ', $possible_keywords_2));

// Count how many times each keywords from $input appears
$count = array_count_values($input);

// Filter out from $count any keyword that is not present in $keywords
$result = array_intersect_key($count, array_flip($keywords));
```

[**See it in action**](http://www.ideone.com/2q2SQ).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a combination of [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Following is code to start with:

```
$possible_keywords_1_array = explode(",", $possible_keywords_1); 
$possible_keywords_2_array = explode(",", $possible_keywords_2); 
$matches = count(array_intersect($possible_keywords_1_array, $possible_keywords_2_array));
```